# Draw a curve between two set of lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, line-art

Is there an easy way in photoshop to draw the white letters in the blue letters like below?

[image]

At first thought I thought it was a new layer with the letters made smaller, but it is not the way to do it. It seems like every white pixel is more or less at the same distance of the outer blue pixels.

Comment: This one in particular I believe is a font that comes with the line already "included". I don't think this can be (easily) done automatically, because not all letters are regular. Look at the R, for example, the legs would end up all truncated.

Comment: The font is "keep calm" and doesn't include this feature

Comment: ...This looks nothing like the font Keep Calm other than both being sans-serif.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish something similar to this by applying a stroke in the Layer Styles (the 'fx' icon at the bottom of the Layers Panel). Alternatively you may be able to accomplish a similar effect under the Edit > Stroke… menu bar.

[image: Before stroke applied]

[image: After stroke appled]

Comment: I think the question is asking about the **internal path** not a stroke around the outside of something.

Comment: Yes @scott, halfway through I realized he was looking for the reverse, (perhaps I should have included that in my answer) but this is a way to achieve a similar effect in Photoshop. Hopefully it helped. The title of the post was confusing a little too. Thanks.